# jQuery returning wrong selected radiobox?

Tags: jquery, radio-button

I have a form input consisting of two radiobuttons, for one name, as below:

```
<label for="thumb">[thumb]</label> 
<input type="radio" name="type" value="thumb" checked />
<label for="img">[img]</label><input type="radio" name="type" value="img" />
```

Within a jQuery function I reference which one is checked as such:

```
type=$('input[name="type"]').is(':checked').val();
```

For some reason, even if I have changed the checked box on the page, if always returns the former.

Here's the full code, for purposes of elimination:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Thumb/img BBCode generator</title>
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js'></script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css" />
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<noscript>Please enable Javascript or use the <a href='index2.php'>old generator</a></noscript>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Thumb/img BBCode generator for Facepunch</h2>
<div id="content">
<form id="f" action="generate2.php" method="POST">
<label for="thumb">[thumb]</label> 
<input type="radio" name="type" value="thumb" checked />
<label for="img">[img]</label><input type="radio" name="type" value="img" /><br />
<textarea rows="30" cols="40" name="text">Insert image links on seperate lines</textarea><br />
<input type="button" value="Generate!" id="1_c"/>
</form>
</div>
<script>
 $('#1_c').click(function(){
    var text=$('textarea').val(),
    type=$('input[name="type"]').is(':checked').val();
    $.post('generate2.php', { text: text, type: type },
      function(data) {
          $("#content").html(data);
      });
  });
  function reset(){
    history.go('0');
  }
</script>
</body>
```

Live version: http://pdo.elementfx.com/thumb/

Comment: Incidentally, IDs aren't supposed to start with a number, only with an alphabetical letter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem you're running into is the `is` selector returns a boolean value and not the matched element.  This means you end up calling `val()` on `true / false` instead of the radio button.

Try using the following selector intstead

```
type=$('input[name="type"]:checked').val()
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fP2P4/1/

Comment: No it's not...It returns "thumb" every time. I've already tried that.

Comment: @SatansFate I've updated my answer with a fiddle example that demonstrates the selector I recomended

Comment: And i've updated my question with a live example -http://pdo.elementfx.com/thumb/

Comment: @SatansFate your live sample doesn't have the `:checked` suffix on the selector like my example does.  This is necessary to pick the checked one

Comment: Argh, i'm sorry - yet more proof that I'm not cut out for coding. I was editing the archived version.

Comment: @SatansFate eh, part of being a good coder is making dumb mistakes like that. It just happens (and it doesn't go away with experience). :)

Answer (score 1):

Use this instead:

```
type = $('input[name="type"]:checked').val();
```

Using `is(':checked')` returns a Boolean (true/false), which has no `.val()` and triggers an error.

Answer (score 1):

`is(':checked')` returns true if the element is checked. You don't want it to return true or false, you want to select the element that is checked, so use

```
type = $('input[name="type"]:checked').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use $('input[name="type"]').prop('checked'); if you prefer.

edit: http://jsfiddle.net/pVhn8/

Comment: what problem? added fiddle to answer.

Answer (score 0):

The is() method returns a Boolean so it's not clear how you got this statement to work: `$('input[name="type"]').is(':checked').val();`

You should use `$('input[name="type"]:checked').val()` instead.